# Unable to get Data from vendor entity using filter

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

When I am trying with Date I am able tp get data from filter.  But when I am trying to get data from filter using DateTime, I am unable to get Data. Below is my request body:

```
Filter=LastUpdatedTime :AFTER: 2013-06-07T15:00:00-0700 :AND: LastUpdatedTime :BEFORE: 2013-06-07T16:56:35-0700&PageNum=1&ResultsPerPage=100
```

and code:

```
requestBody = String.Format(requestBody, pageNumber, pageSize, After.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"), Before.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"));

                    HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(commonService.ServiceContext.BaseUrl + "vendors/v2/" + commonService.ServiceContext.RealmId) as HttpWebRequest;
                    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
                    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                    string oAuthHeader = GetDevDefinedOAuthHeader(context, httpWebRequest, requestBody);
                    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", oAuthHeader);
                    requestXML.Append(requestBody);
                    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
                    byte[] content = encoding.GetBytes(requestXML.ToString());
```

Please tell me which format of Datetime do I need to send?

Answer (score 0):

This is the data format you need to use:

```
  <StartCreatedTMS>2009-11-17T22:35:08.0Z</StartCreatedTMS> 
  <EndCreatedTMS>2010-01-08T20:54:56.0Z</EndCreatedTMS>
```

thanks
Jarred

Comment: can u explain briefly for the above answer,that how to pass above datetime in request body.